# return inside foreach php and laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

I trying to return data every time inside the foreach() but i keep on getting the data on the first iteration of the loop here is my code

```
  for ($i = 0 ;$i<4;$i++)
    {
        var_dump($i);
        $publisher = Publisher::find($results[$i]->publisherId);
        //pr($publisher);
        $channels =$publisher->channels()->get() ;
        pr($channels[0]);
        $data = ReviveAgent::getPublisherDailyStatistics($channels[0],$start,$end);
        pr($data);
        return Response::json($data);


    }
```

on the var_dump($i);
It only shows data for the first 0 only.So how can i return the data also for 1,2,3

here is my output when pr($data) for var_dump($i) = 1

```
            array (

   0 => 
  array (
'impressions' => 1867,
'clicks' => 14,
'requests' => 44,
'revenue' => 2.79,
'day' => 
stdClass::__set_state(array(
   'scalar' => '20150518T00:00:00',
   'timestamp' => 1431907200,
   'xmlrpc_type' => 'datetime',
    )),
   ),
 1 => 
 array (
'impressions' => 2197,
'clicks' => 17,
'requests' => 382,
'revenue' => 19.829999999999998,
'day' => 
stdClass::__set_state(array(
   'scalar' => '20150519T00:00:00',
   'timestamp' => 1431993600,
   'xmlrpc_type' => 'datetime',
   )),
  ),
  2 => 
    array (
 'impressions' => 5484,
'clicks' => 3,
'requests' => 3680,
'revenue' => 6.7300000000000004,
'day' => 
stdClass::__set_state(array(
   'scalar' => '20150520T00:00:00',
   'timestamp' => 1432080000,
   'xmlrpc_type' => 'datetime',
 )),
 ),
 3 => 
 array (
'impressions' => 6909,
'clicks' => 105,
'requests' => 5141,
'revenue' => 378.88499999999999,
'day' => 
stdClass::__set_state(array(
   'scalar' => '20150521T00:00:00',
   'timestamp' => 1432166400,
   'xmlrpc_type' => 'datetime',
     )),
    ),
```

Comment: How about storing all the received data in an array first and after the for loop you can return it

Comment: let me show my out put on pr($data)

Answer (score 2):

The `return` operator [implicitly ends the current execution scope](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php). The context of your usage is not given, but you could put your `$data` into an `array` prior to JSON encoding and returning it. It might look something like this:

```
$data = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    ...
    $record = ReviveAgent::getPublisherDailyStatistics($channels[0], $start, $end));
    pr($record);
    $data[] = $record;
}
return Response::json($data);
```

Comment: i want the data as json because i want to use the data somewhere

Comment: @ReginwaldtLed - Updated my answer according to your new information given about context + added example.

Comment: i get this error      __clone method called on non-object

Comment: @ReginwaldtLed - Oh, I see that your data is nested arrays in your update. If you remove `clone` what does `var_dump($data)` show after your `foreach` is complete, but before `return`?

Comment: @fantascticrice nested arrays for the last record only

Answer (score 0):

You can take this example in laravel
Here I am  returning multiple Prices

```
$prices = $this->Prices;
foreach ($prices as $price) {

    $res[] = [
        'travel_mode_id' =>$price->travel_mode_id,
        'occupancy_id' => $price->occupancy_id,
        'rider_id' => $price->occupancy_id,
        'price' => $price->price,

    ];
}
return $res;
```